# ¿Cómo puedo hacer commit programáticamente a todos los archivos modificados menos uno?

Tags: regex, bash, svn

estoy intentando filtrar una conjunto de archivos al momento de hacer commit con svn. Se que existen unas propiedades que se pueden establecer para ignorar ciertos archivos pero al final del día siempre termino por descartandolas porque no termina de funcionar de forma correcta.

Para ponerlos en contexto de lo que quiero hacer les doy un ejemplo. Supongamos que quiero hacer commit sobre una carpeta con 5 archivos, al hacer `svn status` se muestra lo siguiente:

```
M       file1
M       file2
!       file3
?       file4
A       file2
```

Supongamos que deseo ignorar las modificaciones del archivo **file2**. Mi enfoque inicial fallido es utilizar una expresión regular y varios comandos de bash para poder realizar `svn commit` sobre las lineas que no tengan **file2**, algo mas o menos así:

```
svn st | grep '[!?AM]\s+(?!file2)' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn commit
```

Si tienen alguna mejor solución o al menos pueden ayudarme a construir la expresión regular que necesito les estaría muy agredido. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517064/exclude-some-files-on-svn-command-line-commit-not-svnignore) en SO original (ignorando la aceptada, por supuesto), podrías:

a) Usar una expresión del estilo:

```
svn ci $(svn stat | grep -v file2 | awk '{print $2}')
```

b) Armar la lista de archivos a hacer commit con perl:

```
svn commit $(svn stat |  grep -v ignore.file | perl -ne 'chop; s/^.\s+//; print "$_ "')
```

En ambas te evitas el lidiar con una expresión regular de la forma que buscabas (lo cual siempre será bueno)

Comment: La primera opción es bastante elegante y simple, creo que para mi es la mejor. Muchas gracias. :)